# Linear model overfit due to too many covariates?

Tags: r, lm, anova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linear model overfitting  due to too many covariates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/linear-model-overfitting-due-to-too-many-covariates)

My study design involves a control and 2 test groups plus some covariates.
Each group consists of around 20 observations. In total I look at around a 1000 variables.

I created a linear model using the `lm` function in R including 2 covariates. After that I thought I include another covariate because doing a PCA plot earlier showed a slight effect on that covariate. However, after adding this covariate to the model 50% of the significant hits are now different. I was actually assuming that it would pretty much identical as the effect was hardly seen in the PCA.

Could it be that I have overfitted the model? Or is the effect simple just not shown in the PCA plot but is there?

I just compared the two models using `anova(lm1, lm2)` and the p-value is significant which I think means that the third covariate adds significant information to the model?

```
lm1 <- lm(var ~ factor_of_interest + cov1 + cov2)
lm2 <- lm(var ~ factor_of_interest + cov1 + cov2 + cov3)

anova(lm1, lm2)
```

Comment: Just to check whether I read this right: you're saying you have about $60$ observations and $1000$ variables of interest?

Comment: Yes it would be useful to know what your definition of `var` is. Can you post a `head(yourdata,20)` here? As @Macro points out, you cannot calculate 1000 OLS coefficients from 60 observations. Also I don't know what a PCA plot is, please elaborate.